# Rails Custom Validation Errors using en.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model user_input.rb

```
class UserInput
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  # attributes
  attr_accessor :patientNum, :recordLimit
  validates_presence_of :patientNum

  validates :patientNum, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}

  def initialize(attributes={})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=",value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

When I receive error messages I get messages like

"Patientnum is not a number"

I want to change Patientnum to "Patient Number"

My current en.yml file is

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"

  errors:
    format: "%{message}"

  user_input:
    attributes:
      patientNum: "Patient Number"
```

This is tricky for me because my model is not an ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  attributes:
    patientNum: "Patient ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveModel::Validations` uses `ActiveModel::Translation` to generate the human readable attribute name that is used in the error message.

For your class and attribute names, it will look for the following I18n keys, in this order:

1. `activemodel.attributes.user_input.patientNum`
2. `attributes.patientNum`

If those aren't found, it will fall back to the default value, which is `'patientNum'.humanize`.

See the implementation of [`ActiveModel::Translation#human_attribute_name`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/342de05/activemodel/lib/active_model/translation.rb#L43) for details.